# Twilio Conversations API Realtime chat

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

basically I just want a simple chat integration by using twilio conversations api. With the docs I already set up a server and I created a conversation and added 2 participants to the conversation itself by the mentioned api endpoints. Its also obvious to me how to create a message looking at the docs. Im wondering how I can refresh update the chat message for participant B if participant a is sending a message.

Do I need to configure some kind of `websockets` or is this not needed for the conversations api? How would i notify the participant b and display the new message in real time?

And if I need `websockets`, why should I need twilio conversations api then?

Answer (score 1):

Twilio Conversations provides [client side SDKs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/sdk-download-install) that you can use to display conversations and messages to your chat users. Check out the [JavaScript Conversations Quickstart](https://www.twilio.com/docs/conversations/javascript/exploring-conversations-javascript-quickstart) to see how you can use it to build chat for your users.

Comment: Hey there, thank you for your reply. Am I able to use it as realtime chat? I don't see any hint to this in the sdk docs.